# Does Thunderbird Ubuntu One contacts sync work in 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird, contacts

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and am trying to get my contacts in Thunderbird to sync to Ubuntu One.

I thought it would just be a case of saving them in the Ubuntu One address book, which I have done, but these contacts do not appear in the Ubuntu One web portal.  Neither do the contacts that I already have existing in Ubuntu One (from an old experiment with Evolution) get pulled down to the address book.

The Ubuntu One console shows that Contacts sync is enabled and I can't find anywhere else that I might be able to configure anything to do with this.  Everything else in Ubuntu One seems to be working fine with this machine.

Can anyone confirm if this actually works and if so, how to go about setting it up

Comment: Contact Sync with Ubuntu One doesn't work for me either. Although I have checked "Enable Contacts Sync" in the Ubuntu One Control Panel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is that I've disabled and then reenabled the Contacts Sync on Ubuntu One Control panel and restarted Thunderbird and all the contacts were then there.

Comment: Excellent!  Now it works!  I'm sure I tried this before and it made no difference - the Ubuntu One status was updated yesterday to say that they are still adding more servers to cope with load so maybe that is what has fixed it.

Comment: Nod: it wasn't working for me back in October '11. I figured it was hopeless and then one day ... poof. There it was.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Service Status page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status) at [one.ubuntu.com](https://one.ubuntu.com/):

> **2011-11-02** Syncing of contacts is not working for some users due to server issues. On 2011-10-10 we released an update to all clients to help ease the load on the server and improve reliability of syncing. We're now working on finishing up adding additional server hardware.

As such, it is not working personally for me at the time of this writing. However, the way one would set up the contact sync is through the Ubuntu One control panel interface:

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu One control panel]

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that is why it is not working for me but as I only tried to use it since they had server problems I guess I won't know until they sort it.  Did it work for you before the server issue ?  Also, it looks like this has been down for nearly a month - are outages of this length usual for Ubuntu One?

Comment: @JonReeves This last worked for me with Evolution during 11.04, I think. I'm hoping that as time goes on we won't be having anymore outages lasting this long...they had a similar problem for Firefox bookmark sync not working right and they eventually discontinued it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Ubuntu One.
2. Create/login with your Launchpad ID.
3. Click on *Services*.
4. Make sure *Enable contact sync* is marked.

There, you are done.

Comment: Already checked that.  Can you confirm that this is working for you?  I've just noticed the Ubuntu One service status says that there are some performance issues with contacts sync at the moment so that may be why I'm having problems