# Import Gmail contacts into Thunderbird via Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird, gmail

I've just started using Ubuntu One. It tells me I can import my Gmail contacts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail is a great email service and Thunderbird is one heck of a free email client.  Adding your Gmail account to Thunderbird is very simple and straight forward

[And then reenabled the Contacts Sync on Ubuntu One Control panel and restarted Thunderbird and all the contacts were then there.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72065/does-thunderbird-ubuntu-one-contacts-sync-work-in-11-10)

http://www.howtogeek.com/79968/import-gmail-contacts-into-thunderbird/

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+import+gmail+contact+in+thunderbird