# How to sync Contacts in 12.04 with Thunderbird / Ubuntu One?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-one, 12.04, thunderbird, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thunderbird Contacts sync with Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101650/thunderbird-contacts-sync-with-ubuntu-one)

How to get Google Contacts to sync with Thunderbird / Ubuntu One in Ubuntu [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/tags/12.04/info) Beta?

I want to sync Google Contacts with Thunderbird, ultimately to allow using the Unity Contacts lens from the Ataraeo PPA: https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/lenses

***Note: This question is not a duplicate of previous questions:***
["Import Gmail contacts into Thunderbird via Ubuntu One?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100493/import-gmail-contacts-into-thunderbird-via-ubuntu-one) or ["Thunderbird Contacts sync with Ubuntu One"](https://askubuntu.com/q/101650/2383) or ["How to sync Ubuntu One Contacts with thunderbird?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117208/how-to-sync-ubuntu-one-contacts-with-thunderbird).  Previous solutions do not work on 12.04 Beta.

In previous versions of Ubuntu One there was a sync contacts button.

See: 11.04 screenshot [image].

In ubuntu 12.04 Beta there is no sync contacts function.

See: [image]

This is a screenshot of the desired Unity Contacts lens in action:

[image: unity contacts lens]
link to Unity Contacts lens PPA: https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/lenses

Comment: I've added a bounty to get a 12.04 update on the parent question.